# Safari hangs if Javascript array size > 4

Tags: javascript

Given a `start` and `end` date, I am trying to create an array with the beginning and ending dates of all the weeks between the `start` and `end` date.

The code in question below works when the number of weeks between the `start` and `end` dates is 4 or less. If it's more it simply hangs.

Could some one please explain to me what is happening or at least point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
function getWeeklyTimePeriod(start_d, end_d) {

    var weekly = [];
    var end_dstr =  $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', end_d);

    var sd = new Date(start_d);
    while (true) {
        var ed = new Date(sd);
        ed.setDate(sd.getDate() + (6-(sd.getDay())));

        sd_str = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', sd);
        ed_str = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', ed);

        if (ed < end_d) {
            weekly.push({ "start": sd_str, "end": ed_str });
            sd.setDate(ed.getDate() + 1);
        } else {
            weekly.push({ "start": sd_str, "end": end_dstr });
            console.log("OUT");
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(weekly);
    return weekly;
}
```

Comment: `ed < end_d` is never true so your loop never breaks. Open debugger, put a breakpoint and see why it is so.

Comment: You're getting a date overflow. At some point, `sd` transitions into the next month, and `ed` is going to get an unexpected value.

Comment: Are *start_d* and *end_d* Date objects?

Comment: @Bergi—shouldn't be a problem, provided *start_d* and *end_d* are Date objects.

Comment: @zerkms— *ed* is set to the Saturday following the start on each loop, and start is incremented to the Sunday following the previous Saturday on each loop too.

Comment: @RobG not sure I see the point. The fact is that the condition is never `false` (yep, made a mistake) :-) PS: I did not even try to read the code, it does not matter for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @RobG: I've got that backwards, sorry. The problem is that `sd.setDate(ed.getDate() + 1);` does *not* always set the start to the sunday following the saturday: in the case that `ed.setDate(sd.getDate() + …)` did overflow into the next month, so that `ed.getDate()` is then unexpectedly small (instead of being `sd + 6days`).

Comment: @Bergi—yes, you're right. The start date is being **set** not incremented, so it never ticks over to the next month, then the end date is reset based on the start date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi pointed out, your problem is here:

```
        sd.setDate(ed.getDate() + 1);
```

When *ed* ticks over to the next month, it's date is say 5 and *sd*'s date is say 29. So this sets *sd* to 6 **in the same month**, so it doesn't tick over to the 6th of the next month but goes back to the 6th of its current month.

Then in the loop the end date is reset to the next Saturday back in the original month and an endless loop ensues.

Replace it with:

```
        sd = new Date(ed);
        sd.setDate(sd.getDate() + 1);
```

and you're good to go. Below is a refactored example, I much prefer do..while to a `while(true)` loop with a break:

```
function dString(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return z(d.getDate()) + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) +'-' + d.getFullYear();
}

function getWeeklyTimePeriod(start_d, end_d) {

    var weekly = [],
        sd = new Date(start_d),
        ed;

    do {
        ed = new Date(sd);
        ed.setDate(ed.getDate() + (6-(ed.getDay())));

        weekly.push({ "start": dString(sd), "end": dString(ed) });
        sd = new Date(ed);
        sd.setDate(sd.getDate() + 1);

    } while (ed < end_d)

    return weekly;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getWeeklyTimePeriod(new Date(2015,7,28), new Date(2015,8,13))));
```

Comment: Much thanks. That worked but with a slight modification. In my case I needed the last week to be within the `end` date. So I changed it accordingly. Also, why do you have a complicated implementation for `dString` when in fact `return $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d)` would have worked?

Comment: Happy to help. ;-) Re *dString*: to create a stand–alone example (took about a minute to write).